# Prevx vs ThreatFire ... what they do that the other can't?

Tags: anti-virus

http://www.prevx.com/ Prevx

http://www.threatfire.com/ ThreatFire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero day threats on ThreatFire, it doesn't need signatures to identify a threat.

Answer (score 0):

Well u can take a look at these videos that show a real malware attack against PrevX and ThreatFire

[ThreatFire](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bo3oPErZxo)

[PrevX](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAx6Y2MW_uA)